# How to evaluate $\int x^5 (1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, binomial-theorem

I am trying to evaluate $\int x^5 (1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}} dx$

---

This is apparently a binomial integral of the form $\int x^m (a+bx^k)^ndx$. Therefore, we can use Euler's substitutions in order to evaluate it. Since $\dfrac{m+1}{k} = \dfrac{5+1}{2} = 3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ we will use the substitution: $$ a+bx^k = u^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Therefore,

$$ u^3 = 1 + x^2 \iff x = \sqrt{u^3 +1} \text{ (Mistake Here. Check the comments) } $$ $$\iff dx = \frac{3u^2}{2\sqrt{u^3}+1}$$

So the new integral is,

$$ \int x^5 (1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}} dx = \frac{3}{2} \int u^4 (u^3+1)^{\frac{7}{6}} du$$

---

Instead of simplifying the integral, the substitution did nothing by keeping it at the same form, with different values on the variables $m,k,n$.

I tried to substitute once again and it doesn't seem to lead in any known paths, anytime soon.

Any ideas on how this could be evaluated?

Comment: There is  always the horribly unpleasant option of setting $u = 1 + x^2$, distributing everything out and using the power rule. I encourage you to come up with something more clever, but this will at least work.

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{x^3-1}$

Comment: @LL3.14 Indeed. I edited. But still, I couldn't solve it, same thing happened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**HINT:**
Let $1+x^2=t^3\implies 2xdx=3t^2dt$ or $xdx=\frac{3}{2}t^2dt$
$$\int x^5(1+x^2)^{2/3}dx=\int (x^2)^2(1+x^2)^{2/3}xdx$$

$$=\int (t^3-1)^2(t^3)^{2/3}\ \frac{3t^2}{2}dt$$
$$=\frac32\int(t^3-1)^2t^4 dt $$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int (t^{10}-2t^7+t^4)dt$$

Comment: Surprisingly easy after this clever substitution. +1 cool.

Answer (score 2):

Do the substitution $u^{3/5} = 1+ x^2$. Then $x = \sqrt{u^{3/5}-1}$, so $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{3\,u^{-2/5}}{5\,\sqrt{u^{3/5}-1}}\,\mathrm d u$ and
$$
∫ x^5 \,(1+x^2)^{2/3}\,\mathrm d x = \frac{3}{5}∫ (u^{3/5}-1)^2 \,\mathrm d x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, denote $x^2=t\Rightarrow 2xdx=dt$:
$$\int x^5 (1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}dx=\frac12\int t^2 (1+t)^{\frac{2}{3}}dt=\\
\frac12\int (t^2-1+1)(1+t)^{\frac23}dt=\int(t-1)(1+t)^\frac53dt+\int(1+t)^\frac23dt=\\
\frac12\int(t+1-2)(1+t)^{\frac53}dt+\frac12\int(1+t)^{\frac23}dt=\\
\frac12\int(1+t)^{\frac83}dt-\int (1+t)^{\frac53}dt+\frac12\int(1+t)^{\frac23}dt=\\
\frac3{22}(1+t)^{\frac{11}3}-\frac3{8}(1+t)^{\frac{8}3}+\frac3{10}(1+t)^{\frac{5}3}+C$$
Now, plug $t=x^2$ and you are done.
Wolfram alpha [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20x%5E5%20%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D%7Ddx) and [comparison](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac3%7B22%7D%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B11%7D3%7D-%5Cfrac3%7B8%7D%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B8%7D3%7D%2B%5Cfrac3%7B10%7D%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B5%7D3%7D%3D%203%2F440%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%201%29%5E%285%2F3%29%20%2820%20x%5E4%20-%2015%20x%5E2%20%2B%209%29).

Answer (score 0):

Take $x^5 \times (1 + x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}} = (x^{15} \times (1+x^2)^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ or some other form of that sort and integrate.

Thus, you'll be integrating $(x^{19} + 2x^{17} + x^{15})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Applying substitution method here may work.

Comment: Was this worth the thought ?

Answer (score 0):

**Generalization**

For

$$I=\int x^{m-1+rm}(x^m+c)^p\ dx$$

Set $x^m+c=y,dy=?$

$$mI=\int(y-c)^ry^p\ dy$$

Now use Binomial expansion